# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined while executing dispatch function after fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I  am trying to post an image to Cloudinary with fetch API.

My code seems to be running file as I am getting URL back and able to store it in state.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Please help me understand what I am missing on..

```
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const fileForUpload = fileInputRef.current.files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileForUpload);
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'xprl6rwq');
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    };

    return fetch(
      'https://api.Cloudinary.com/v1_1/antilibrary/image/upload',
      options
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res =>
        dispatch({
          type: SET_FILEURL,
          payload: res.secure_url
        }).then(addAddOnDataToDb())
      );
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure your dispatch is returning a promise?

Comment: Can you please help me understand

Comment: you are chaining `then` (a promise method) to dispatch rather than fetch (promise based). in order to be able to do that, dispatch itself must return a promise.